# How do you add custom rows to a DataList that is already using a SqlDataSource in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have a DataList that is retrieving data from a SqlDataSource, how can I append custom rows to my DataList that the SqlDataSource doesn't return? I need to add custom rows based on criteria that cannot be taken from a query (Ie. if I have this result and this result, I need to add a custom row..)

Comment: [Your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449470/how-to-add-values-programmatically-to-a-datalist-datasource-in-asp-net) was better. If it isn't getting enough attention, try adding more detail. Don't open another question.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev, I thought the other question was a bit loaded with detail, I wanted to separate it out to make each question (of the larger whole) manageable

Answer (score 0):

You could replace your `sqldatasource` with a datalist entirely and bind the datalist to gridview. but before binding add the custom rows to the datalist. for example -

```
public class item
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public decimal amount {get;set;}
}
```

suppose this is the object whose list you want to bind to the gridview

```
List<item> list = getItems(); // returns all items as a list
list.Add(new item{ id=5, name="orange", amount = 3m}); //adding custom item
gridView1.DataSource = list;
gridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I agree, but if he is using a SQLDataSource, do you think he has a function like getItems()?

Comment: But as @MikeSmithDev said, I do not have a method getItems() nor am I using a GridView

Comment: Well, I am suggesting to not use sqldatasource. instead right a method like `getItems()` which will return list of all items from your database. then use this list to you liking. you can use `sqldatareader` inside `getItems` method to generate the list.